# background image in css style from static files with django

Tags: css, django, image, django-staticfiles

I used this [template](https://templated.co/hielo) to create a home page in a django project, however I can't have the background image displayed correctly (bg.jpg)

The background image is used as foollows in the css file :

```
.wrapper.style3 {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #bfbfbf;
    background-image: url(/media/usr/path_to_project/project_name/home/static/images/bg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

I read these topics

- [How to add background image in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170310/how-to-add-background-image-in-css)
- [How to use background image in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359479/how-to-use-background-image-in-css)
- [use static image in css, django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956205/use-static-image-in-css-django)
- [How do I put a background image on the body in css with django using static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112050/how-do-i-put-a-background-image-on-the-body-in-css-with-django-using-static)

and tried all of the solutions but non of them seems to work.

My project tree is like

```
project_name
- home
- static
--home
---style.css
--images
---bg.jpg
- templates
-- home
---base.html
---home_template.html
```

in the style.css file I tried the following

```
background-image: url(/media/usr/path_to_project/project_name/home/static/images/bg.jpg);

background-image: url("/media/usr/path_to_project/project_name/home/static/images/bg.jpg");

background-image: url(../images/bg.jpg);

background-image: url("../images/bg.jpg");

background-image: url("{% static 'images.bg.jpg' %});
```

in my base.html template I have :

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'home/style.css' %}"/>
```

and in my home_template.html I have

```
{% block body %}
{% load staticfiles %}

        <section id="two" class="wrapper style3">
            <div class="inner">
                <header class="align-center">
                    <p>Nam vel ante sit amet libero scelerisque facilisis eleifend vitae urna</p>
                    <h2>Morbi maximus justo</h2>
                </header>
            </div>
        </section>

{% endblock %}
```

The strange thing is that I have other images in my static/images directory that are displayed fine in the template with inline styling such as :

```
<div class="image fit">
<img src="{% static 'images/pic03.jpg' %}" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: maybe your image is corrupted, or smth similar happend with me before and the problem was that the image was `.JPG` in caps not small. try opening the the img from the url directly to know if it is a css problem or not?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should simply use `background-image: url('/static/images/bg.jpg');`, since Django automatically maps `/static` to the correct folder.

Answer (score 2):

There is a special setting that handles how static files are served: [STATIC_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_URL).

That is the correct path to use.

Answer (score 0):

From [Django's official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial06/#adding-a-background-image) (version 4.2):

> For the purposes of this tutorial, we’re using a file named
> **background.png**, which will have the full path **polls/static/polls/images/background.png**.
>
> Then, add a reference to your image in your stylesheet
> (**polls/static/polls/style.css**):

```
body {
    background: white url("images/background.png") no-repeat;
}
```

I guess this is the preferred method, since they teach it that way. From the same tutorial, they say that the Jinja templating is not available in CSS files:

> The `{% static %}` template tag is not available for use in static files
> which aren’t generated by Django, like your stylesheet.